# Delphi 2009 Function eliminated by linker

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I want to use the function `DateTimeToStr` while debugging a project. I want to use either the evaluate/modify window, or the watch window. This always results in the error "Function eliminated by linker".

I've ensured that the function is used by the project (I also placed a call explicitly in the function I want to debug), also I turned off  the optimization and recompiled the whole project.

Answer (score 7):

I made the following program

```
program WhereDidItGo;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  SysUtils;

begin
  DateTimeToStr(0.0);
end.
```

And found exactly what you report. The evaluate/modify window reports that the function was eliminated. Weird.

Anyway, I tried this, which seemed to be enough to trick it.

```
program WhyDoesThisSolveTheOddity;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  SysUtils;

var
  FunctionPtr: function(const DateTime: TDateTime): string;
  VarFalse: Boolean;

begin
  if VarFalse then
    FunctionPtr := @DateTimeToStr;
end.
```

Perhaps the issue is that the function is declared as being `inline`. Although in my tests, the function call was not actually being inlined.

Comment: What happens when you assign the result of the `DateTimeToStr` to a used variable (there can be difference in when you use this variable or not) ? I don't have Delphi by hand now but if I'd be a compiler I would eliminate that just because such function call makes no sense.

Comment: @TLama You mean in `WhereDidItGo`? It makes no difference whether or not you assign the return value to anything.

Comment: Hi David thx for the fast reply. That works at least when pressing alt+f7 and evaluate it. but when you add it to the list of the watched expressions the value is not available.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. You should certainly report this to QC.

Comment: I don't have 2009 installed anywhere any longer, so I can't check. Will check in another version later, though. I'll clean up here now. (And yes, the compiler will remove meaningless code, such as a loop that does nothing but increment a variable that is never used outside that loop.) `for i := 1 to 10 do inc(j);` will be eliminated if `j` is never used after the loop executes if optimization is on. Try it, and try to set a breakpoint on the `inc(j);` line.

Comment: @Ken Yes, it will do that. But it never eliminates procedure calls.